# overwrite getter of es6 class instance

Tags: ecmascript-6, getter

In this example I try to overwrite getter with cached value.

it doesn't works.

Is it possible to overwrite getter of a class instance?

```
class Module {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id
  }
  get element() {
    const elm = document.getElementById(id)
    if(!elm) throw new Error(`#${id} is not in document`)
    delete this.element;
    this.element = elm;
    return elm;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are looking to memoize, and I saw this implementation that is similar to Michal's answer: https://github.com/taras/memoize-getters/blob/master/src/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
class Module {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id
  }
  get element() {
    const elm = document.getElementById(this.id)
    if(!elm) throw new Error(`#${id} is not in document`)
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'element', {
      value: elm,
    });
    return elm;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank! can I remove line `delete this.element;`

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski no, it does not remove the getter, it simply *shadows* the inherited getter

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the correction. I thought the getter was removed, because `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` didn't return the getter, but I forgot it only checks for *own* properties.